# source for the mitzva to walk in Israel

Tags: eretz-yisrael, mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

what is the source that every four amot (~2 meters) walked in Israel is a mitzva? (read this somewhere)

Also, what is the reason for this mitzva if it has any.

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If there is additional information that you would like, consider clarifying what it is.

Answer (score 6):

[aish](http://www.aish.com/atr/Mitzvah_to_Live_in_Israel.html) brings the sources

> You shall possess the Land and dwell in it - [Bamidbar 33:53](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.33.53?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)

and the **gemara in [Ketubot 111a](http://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.111a.74?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all)**

> Whoever walks four amot in the Land of Israel may rest assured that he will be a denizen of the World to Come

[Ohr Somayach](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/217/Q3/) cites the Maharal explaining the reason

> Because of the intrinsic Holiness of the Land of Israel, a person
>   gains spiritual merit by merely walking here

See also [aish](http://www.aish.com/atr/Mitzvah_to_Live_in_Israel.html) for more details on the relevance of this mitzva today

> The question, however, is whether this mitzvah is compulsory in our
>   times when the Holy Temple is not standing. This is the basis of a
>   dispute between two great Talmudic commentators, Maimonides and
>   Nachmanides. A leading 20th century sage, Rabbi Moshe Feinstein,
>   concludes that living in Israel is a "mitzvah kiyuma" – while it is a
>   great mitzvah, there is no absolute obligation to do so.

See also [here](http://www.yutorah.org/togo/haatzmaut/articles/Yom_Haatzmaut_To-Go_-_5770_Rabbi_Flug.pdf)

Comment: IMO, this is the best answer of all given. Please post it to the original question (this is marked as a duplicate of a duplicate: )

Comment: @LN6595 thanks for your kind comment - I have now done just that